# How to add emmet support in ace js code editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ace-editor, emmet

I am trying to embed [ace code editor](http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace/#nav=about) in my project. I am initializing my code editor with following code and now I want to enable [emmet js](http://docs.emmet.io/) features. I can see the ext-emmet.js extension is already their in the src directory of ace.js [pre-packaged version](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/tree/master/src)

I need help in enabling [emmet](http://docs.emmet.io/) extension features. So here is my initialization code.

```
  var e = ace.edit("editorId"); // id of the code editor div 
  e.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
  e.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
  e.setBehavioursEnabled(true);
  e.getSession().setTabSize(2);
```

Obviously I am adding the ace.js on top of the page. I can provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Lines 539-543](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/c3403f1fbdf22cfff2cb1dda584b8e04467cd372/demo/kitchen-sink/demo.js#L539-L543) in ace demo.

Basically you need to load emmet source script (e.g. from https://github.com/nightwing/emmet-core/blob/master/emmet.js) and ace extension from /src/ext-emmet.js
call `require("ace/ext/emmet");` so that requirejs executes the script
And after that call `editor.setOption("enableEmmet", true);`.
See jsbin.com/ace-emmet/1/edit for live demo.

Comment: I have tried adding both extension and emmet.js and after setting the option to true as you mentioned, nothing happened. I have added ace.js, ext-emmet.js and emmet.js from your link in my html page header and have made sure that they are loading. It does not even throw any error. I think there is more to it.

Comment: please see http://jsbin.com/ace-emmet/1/edit
you need to add `require("ace/ext/emmet");` so that requirejs executes the script

Comment: Yes Thanks. It works. I have just edited your answer above and the example provided by you.